# Terminology for "New Yorker" vs "lives in New York"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, phrase-requests, terminology

What are the terms that can be used to differentiate between these two nouns?

> *New Yorker* versus *one who lives in New York*

A "New Yorker" would be someone who self-identifies as a practitioner of "New York" culture and values, as opposed to someone who only lives there geographically.

In other words, how would you say something along the lines of *"It was telling that someone was described using the XYZ 'New Yorker,' rather than the ABC 'someone who lives in New York'*?

Comment: By the way, *doer* can be defined as 'someone who does something' so that there's no *versus* as such. (I do understand the underlying question, though. I've upvoted.)

Comment: Those three examples are fundamentally different structures that have little in common. The only thing common to them is that you can rephrase their meaning with a verbal phrase, which can be done with just about any noun (that's what dictionaries normally do). _New Yorker_ is a **demonym** (also **gentilic**); _diabetic_ is a **nominalised adjective**; and _author_ is an **agent noun** (though not your standard, regular one because it was borrowed as an agent noun, rather than derived, and has no corresponding verb _*auth_). The only term I can think of that covers all three is **noun**.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Re "has no corresponding verb," see: "agent noun from *auctus,* past participle of *augere* "to increase" (see *augment* ). Meaning "one who sets forth written statements" is from late 14c. " http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=author

Comment: @Kris _Augere_ is Latin, not English. Like I said, _author_ was borrowed as an agent noun, derived as such in a different language, and has no corresponding verb _*auth_ (in English, that is). It was not derived from the verb in English itself, which makes it an atypical, non-transparent agent noun.

Comment: @Janus I believe you have an answer to this question (as currently written) in your [earlier comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/185993/terminology-for-new-yorker-vs-lives-in-new-york#comment386772_185993)

Comment: I clarified the question and voted to reopen it in its current form.

Comment: I suppose I'd call one a demonym and the other a noun with a restrictive clause although I don't see how this could be useful.

Comment: @emodendroket Why would it have to be useful? .....just curious how to refer to different parts of speech.

Comment: @AnotherUser I mean that like... they're just descriptions of two constructions; they're not actually related to each other.

Comment: @emodendroket "they're not actually related to each other" .....that's _wonderful_, but I'm looking for words to use to describe that. [meaning, how would you say something along the lines of "it was telling that someone was described using the XYZ "New Yorker," rather than the ABC "someone who lives in New York"]

Comment: @AnotherUser In that case, you're better served by just calling them "phrases" or "constructions" than busting out grammatical terms that are largely ill-understood by lay people.

Comment: @emodendroket You are correct, but I'm still curious as to what words to use....there are many terms that I know are correct, and use to help myself think, but would rarely use in conversation with others for exactly that reason (".... _largely ill-understood by lay people_")

Answer (score 2):

There's significant difference from a semantic point of view, more than structural/ grammatical.

Noun phrases with a verb or any other POS component are more explicit and 'simpler:'

> lives in New York

Verb qualifies noun creating a new noun, 'New Yorker.'

On the other hand, nouns/ noun-phrases without this are implicit and 'enriched.'

> diabetic

Requires the reader to extract additional semantic content 'person' and 'having/ suffering from/ diagnosed with' that is not expressly stated.

There are no specific terms to describe these forms that I know of. However, the enriched form is used for brevity while the plainer alternative is better for improved readability.

In some cases, the semantics can be more taxing, especially in instances where the real noun is to be generated by a semantic synthesis, as in:

> Author *vs* writes books

Neither 'writes' nor 'books' is the entity being referred. A *Bahuvrīhi* (बहुव्रीहि, Sk.) compound noun "that refers to a thing which is itself not part of the compound" <sup>[WP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bahuvr%C4%ABhi)</sup>

Comment: None of the nouns given here are bahuvrīhi. A bahuvrīhi is an exocentric compound noun that means specifically “one who has X1 X2/X2s” (where X1 is the first member of the compound and X2 is the second member). _New Yorker_, _diabetic_, and _author_ are not compounds at all, and something like _book-writer_ for the last example is a synthetic compound, not a bahuvrīhi.

Comment: Kris -- I'm going to change my question (as per http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/5035/74434), limit it to just NY (and may or may not ask other questions for the other examples).....you may want to be prepared to edit your answer to fit.

Comment: Kris -- question has been changed (though unfortunately not yet re-opened) .... just to let you know!

Answer (score 1):

I would say that "a citizen of or living in a place" is a [*demonym*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonym), and "having the culture of a place" is an [*ethnic demonym*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonym#Ethnic_demonyms).

> He is French. (a French citizen) - demonym
>
> He is French. (an Australian citizen of French ancestry) - ethnic demonym

Both from Wikipedia's article on demonyms.